# Data not being sent between multiple class methods without direct insertion

Tags: php, class, methods

I have a class I'm developing whose methods call each other and send data,

```
Class Template(){

   public variables = array('text' => 'test');

    public function loadTemplate( $filename ){           

        require PROJECT_PATH .DS. $filename;
    }

    public function render(){

       extract($this->variables);
       $this->loadTemplate('index.php');
    }

}
```

index.php now displays the extracted variables

```
<html>
<body>
      <?php

      var_dump($text);

        ?>
</html>
```

But now it doesnt display NULL values!! but when I require it directly, it works, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is that you need to move the `extract()` call into the function that actually issues the `require` call.

The longer answer is that `extract()` extracts the variables into the current function's scope. When you call the new function to actually require the template, it has a fresh scope. In fact, you'd only have access to the `$filename` variable.

One other point, **please** add `EXTR_SKIP` as the second argument to [`extract()`](http://php.net/extract) so that it doesn't overwrite the filename (and hence turn into a security vulnerability):

```
function loadTemplate($filename) {
    extract($this->variables, EXTR_SKIP);
    require PROJECT_PATH .DS. $filename;
}
```

Or don't store it in a variable at all:

```
function render() {
    extract($this->variables);
    require $this->findTemplatePath("index.php");
}

function findTemplatePath($template) {
    return PROJECT_PATH .DS. $filename;
}
```